# Drawdio the sound is very very low :S?

Tags: capacitor, sound

im a beginner at electronics.
im trying make an drawdio circuit with the instructions in the link below:
http://www.ladyada.net/make/drawdio/drawdio2schem.png
i have following components on the circuit.

- NE555N 555 timer
- PN2907 transistor
- 100uF 25V capacitor **(instead of 6.3v one on the ladyada's page)**
- 680pF ceramic capacitor
- 0.1uF non-ceramic capacitor **( instead of ceramic one on ladyada's page)**
- 1/4W 5% 10 MEGAohm resistor
- 1/4W 5% 10 ohm resistor
- 1/4W 5% 300K resistor
- Small 8ohm speaker 0.5w

do you think any of those changes i made might be causing low sound problem??
please help :/

Comment: All the components and values sound like they're ok. Just a brief point, did you connect all 5 Vcc connections to the positive of the battery? It's also worth checking to see if you put the electrolytic capacitor the right way round

Comment: i connected wires as it is shown in the circuit scheme.

Comment: Try asking at http://forums.adafruit.com/

Comment: That design doesn't seem too robust on the audio amp section.  You might want to try hooking this up to a general purpose amplified speaker.

Comment: After looking at the Drawdio website, they all seem to be quite loud even the one's using the circuit design you've linked to, you might need to post a picture of your circuit so we can check it visually for anything that's obvious. I also agree with Joby too, the Adafruit forum would be a good port of call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does ladyada recommend the 2N2907? I did not see a label on the schematic.

Since the transistor is being used as a switch a better choice would be a 2N3906
which has much lower Vbe(sat) and Vce(sat) specifications.